# custom cursor blinks on hover - css , html

Tags: html, css, cursor

I'm developing this website 
www.goldensprocketzmedia.com/BlackTheme

I'm using a custom  cursor. 
.png file for chrome n firefox
.cur file for IE

The cursor works perfectly fine on chrome and firefox
but on IE the cursor behaved wired when i hover it on a link. It kind of blinks n then gets back to normal. also lags.

the css code isbelow

```
a, a:hover{cursor: url(../../../../cursors/camera.png), /* Modern - relative to the document */
            url(cursors/camera.cur), /* IE - relative to the root */
            default; /* Built-in fallback */} /*new line added*/

    body{width:100%;padding-top:3em;background-color:transparent;color:#abaaaa;font-family:"Open Sans",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:400;
    cursor: url(../../../../cursors/camera.png), /* Modern - relative to the document */
            url(cursors/camera.cur), /* IE - relative to the root */
            default; /* Built-in fallback */    
}
```

Could someone help me in solving this problem.

thanks

Comment: Link needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Gemtastic : posted the css code that i used.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `default` to `auto`.

Comment: tried changing to auto. Doest work yet. The problem is only on IE

Comment: I understand.  It seemed to behave better when I added it, but I don't have the patience to debug things in IE for longer than a few minutes.